# File not found error with mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, import

I'm setting up a local database for gene annotation following the instructions on [this page](http://blast2go.bioinfo.cipf.es/localgodb). They provide an .sql file to create some MySQL table structures (step 4) and several data files to populate the tables (steps 5-7). I've completed the setup process through step 5, but I am getting errors at step 6. What's unnerving is that the error I'm getting is different based on which directory I execute the `mysqlimport` command from.

```
standage@farnsworth:~$ mysqlimport -u wendel2go -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' b2g Desktop/gene2accession 
Enter password: 
mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/Desktop/gene2accession' (Errcode: 2), when using table: gene2accession
standage@farnsworth:~$ cd Desktop/
standage@farnsworth:~/Desktop$ mysqlimport -u wendel2go -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' b2g gene2accession 
Enter password: 
mysqlimport: Error: 29, File '/var/lib/mysql/b2g/gene2accession' not found (Errcode: 2), when using table: gene2accession
```

I'm not getting very informative results when I'm googling this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that the `--local` option was needed. The command worked when I issued it as thus.

```
mysqlimport -u root -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' --local b2g /home/standage/Desktop/gene2accession
```